# Umbraco- weird stylesheet problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, stylesheet, umbraco

I'm developing a user control that will be embedded in Umbraco.  It's been a long slog but I've got it *mostly* working.

At this point I have a template in Umbraco that refers to my web control as a marco.  So far so good.  It looks great in Firefox, but breaks in IE7.

The weird part is that the control looks perfect in both IE7 and Firefox when I view it in my test project, outside of Umbraco.  Inside Umbraco, Firefox looks great and IE7 breaks.  *Some* of the styles are applied in IE7 but not others, breaking the rendering.

I've checked to make sure the CSS files are in the right place in Umbraco, experimented with a few other things, but no luck.  I can't think of anything that would cause IE to break this way only when the control is hosted in Umbraco.  If the CSS files were inaccessible, it should break completely, not apply some of the styles but not others.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EUREKA:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I didn't have it in my template.  Duh.